# Detecting ajax request with PHP on Lighttpd a web server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, lighttpd

I'm having some trouble with detecting a jQuery ajax request with PHP on a  `Lighttpd` web server. Here's the following code (works fine on MAMP and Apache):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
     // ajax (not recognized on lighttpd server)
     echo json_encode(array('success'=>1));
 }
 else {
     // not ajax
 }
```

I thought perhaps there's a certain lighttpd config that's not set correctly, but didn't see anything I recognized. Anyone have any experience with an issue like this?

Thanks!

Comment: What am I looking for here? Thanks

Comment: take the dump from an AJAX request and compare it to a standard request - look for anything which is different between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can have the ajax request append another variable to the query. Then instead of testing for the $_SERVER var, you can simply test for the ajax only $_REQUEST var.

Can you share any of the jQuery code?

Comment: Good answer. I tend to add a GET variable of "mode" - that way I can set it to "ajax" for AJAX operations. Works well.